# Make the text and checkbox side by side

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to put a text and a checkbox side by side in a cell. The expected result likes

[image: demo]

However the actual result is the checkbox is above the text. That means the checkbox takes one line, then the text takes the second line.

My code

```
<kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
       <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
          <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued"> 
 {{dataItem.ProductName}}
       </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
```

Comment: Where is your css? The alignment seems to be fine even without any css.

Comment: There is no css

Comment: Check this JS fiddle, it works fine! https://jsfiddle.net/54j90s27/ Please provide the outer wrapper of this content + any relevant css to this wrapper, it might be that this is limiting the width in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My bad.**

Actually when I created angular component, there was a css file. For some reason I copied and pasted a style into it; I didn't pay attention at it. The style is to set input element width as 95%. I delete it then it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a label:

```
<kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
   <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <input type="checkbox" id="prod-name" class="k-checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued"> 
      <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="prod-name">{{dataItem.ProductName}}</label>
   </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
```

To enable the kendo styles for the checkbox you should add class="k-ckeckbox" to the input.